# How to delete all files by date?

Tags: android

trying to delete all files, which are newer than specified time on versions Q+

```
    val result = resolver.delete(
        MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, "datetaken > ?",
        arrayOf(timestamp.toString())
    )
```

however they are not deleted, result shows always 0.

Comment: Try listing them first. Are you seeing all the files you expect to see?